# Spotipy (sp.track() specifically) takes too long to run

Tags: python, machine-learning, spotify, spotipy, spotify-app

I am trying to extract the release data, explicit flag and popularity score of approximately 18,000 songs. I want to append these results to my data frame

Initially, I tried this. -

```
for i,track in enumerate(df['uri']):
     release_dates.append(sp.track(track)['album']['release_date'])
```

But I took too long to run, so I assumed that it was the size of the dataset that was the problem.

Then I tried to run it over subsets of 50 songs each -

```
updated_popularity, explicit_flags, release_dates = [], [], []

for i in range(0,10000,50):
    print("entered first for loop")
    results = sp.track(df['uri'][i])
    print("got track results")
    for i, t in enumerate(results):
        print("Second loop: Track = ", t)
        updated_popularity.append(t['popularity'])
        explicit_flags.append(t['explicit'])
        release_dates.append(t['album']['release_date'])
    print("Exited second loop\n")
```

However, my code has been running for hours now with no results. I've been stuck on this for a while and any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much faster to request 50 track**s** at once with sp.track**s**(uri_list)

```
# function to divide a list of uris (or ids) into chuncks of 50.
chunker = lambda y, x: [y[i : i + x] for i in range(0, len(y), x)]

# using the function
uri_chunks = chunker(uri_list, 50)

updated_popularity, explicit_flags, release_dates = [], [], []

for chunk in uri_chunks:
    print("entered first for loop")
    results = sp.tracks(chunk)
    print("got tracks results")
    for t in results["tracks"]:
        updated_popularity.append(t['popularity'])
        explicit_flags.append(t['explicit'])
        release_dates.append(t['album']['release_date'])
    print("Exited second loop\n")

print(updated_popularity)
```

Comment: Thank you! I ran this as well, but noticed that it still takes more than an hour (without results). I tried running it on small chunks (10 instead of 50) but the code runs for too long. Is there an issue with the size of my dataset (18,554 songs)? Or maybe is there an issue with my approach?

Comment: @dsispp Smaller chunks mean more requests to the Spotify Web API, and that is slower. I think your script make too many  requests in a short time period, and gets rate-limited. Edit: replaced previous comment and changed my wordings.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to run my code, with chunks of 50, over an hour or so. I restarted my kernel and it ran in under 30 minutes.